# Switch between monitors with dual display state [awesome wm]

Tags: linux, window-manager, awesome, multi-monitor

I'm using Awesome Windows Manager and two display (`LVDS-1` as the secondary display in left and `HDMI-1` as the main display in right). Awesome, by default duplicates screens and I want to switch focus on my display using the keyboard. It's now possible by moving the mouse cursor to each monitor.

Are there any hotkey commands or another way which does not require the mouse?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes there should be.

Try <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> to focus the next screen.

Then <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> should focus the previous screen.

Comment: Also, look `man awesome` for all those things. Inside you can search (by pressing `/`, e.g. `/screen` will jump you to the relevant shortcuts).

Answer (score 1):

The commands to move the mouse from one screen to the next one are :

```
awful.screen.focus_relative (offset)
```

or to a specific screen :

```
awful.screen.focus(_screen)
```

See : https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/screen.html

Example of a key binding :

```
-- to go to next screen
awful.key({ modkey,}, "e", function () awful.screen.focus_relative(1) end)
-- to active screen 2
awful.key({ shift, }, "z", function () awful.screen.focus(2) end)
```